# launching a new emulator for each project I am running

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I run a project it will launching a new emulator for each project.. I cant work all project in same emulator.. How could I solve the problem??

Comment: do you need new emulator or need same emulator for all

Comment: your question is quite confusing

Comment: @Agarwal - I think OP wants to reuse an existing emulator but every project launch is opening a new one. The question is how to avoid that.

Comment: @Ted Hopp but need confirmation from him about his requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:-
When you go to run button in Eclipse, click down button and select Run configurations, in target select manual. Then it will always ask you on which emulator/device do you want to run your application and you can select one you want. For successive applications you can select emulator which is currently online.

Comment: bt it not always gives the option of launching emulator bt my emulator is running..what should i do?

Comment: @Agarwal I am trying to say that each time when i run my differnt project thrn for each project the new emulator launched. I want to run all projects in the same existing emulator

Comment: If you try to run it in manual mode than automatic, then you can decide which emulator to run it.You may want to read this : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-eclipse.html#AutoAndManualTargetModes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you launched your emulator before clicking the run button. Sometimes this becomes a cause of generating this problem.